# JavaFX и векторные изображения

Tags: java, javafx

Подскажите самый простой метод вывода векторного изображения (расширения SVG, допустим) в контейнер в JavaFX? Имеется ли аналог контейнера ImageView и типом Image, который можно поместить с помощью функции ImageView.setImage(Image)?

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант есть. Проверить работоспособность не могу[JavaFxSVG](https://github.com/codecentric/javafxsvg)

Answer (score 0):

Как пишут тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434102/3452146, то `javafx` не поддерживает `svg`, но предлагается костыль - использовать `WebView` и уже там грузить `svg`

Comment: реализация - WebView